# Calculate Overlap Area of 2 Polygons in React

Tags: reactjs, canvas, polygon, overlap

I'm working on a tool where users can mark a specific area on an image based on a question and then evaluate if the marked area is correct. The user is prompted to draw a polygon on the image by clicking on the desired corner points of the shape. Once the user finishes and clicks on evaluate, I need to compare the drawn polygon with the correct polygon stored in the database and calculate the percentage of overlap.

I have the coordinates of all points of the polygon stored in an array. I'll attach some explanatory images.

Does anyone know how I can calculate the overlapping area of the two polygons?

[Initial state:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6XIq.jpg)

[Drawing a few lines:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srUOl.jpg)

[Done Polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNSjj.jpg)

To visualize what I want to calculate, here is an image of 2 Polygons. I want to calculate the area where both colors/polygons overlap.

[2 Polygons:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/id9Zl.png)

I saw a library called turf that does something similar to this only that it uses geographical coordinates and gives back the overlapping area in square meters. This unfortunately only seems to work for geo stuff.